# Capturing key events when they're already being "captured" with `preventDefault` or `stopPropagation`

Tags: javascript, events, google-chrome-extension, preventdefault, keyup

I'm writing a Chrome Extension which injects some code into an existing page. I'm looking to capture a specific key combo, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd>, and the way to do this is easy enough:

```js
document.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
    if(e.ctrlKey && e.key === ";"){
        doSomething();
    }
});
```

This solution works for the "home" of the web app I'm injecting into. However, the "player" is a different story. It seems to be capturing every `keyup` (and probably `keydown`) event on the page and likely using `preventDefault` or `stopPropagation` to prevent these from being passed to the browser for browser things, which also makes my above snippet non-functional.

My question is: how could I go about capturing this key combo when the "player" is enabled? Here's the [full code](https://github.com/ihatecsv/TouchStadia/blob/b1d8559ddcd8a3caae7bc558d932831146f30ce0/touchstadia.js#L395) on GitHub if needed.

As a note: hooking into the "native" JS of this page would be very difficult, as it's *very* obfuscated (think Google).

EDIT: I've tried setting `useCapture`, but this also isn't capturing the `keyup` events, unfortunately:

```js
document.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
    if(e.ctrlKey && e.key === ";"){
        doSomething();
    }
}, true);
```

and

```js
document.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
    if(e.ctrlKey && e.key === ";"){
        doSomething();
    }
}, {useCapture: true});
```

Comment: You could try to set the `useCapture` option to `true` in the `addEventListener`'s arguments.

Comment: Thanks Teemu! Unfortunately, events are not being captured even with `useCapture` set to `true`.

Comment: Umm ... yes, of course, the both listeners are on the document. If you could attach your listener first, but that's probably not possible. Note that the newer syntax is `... , {capture: true}`, it wouldn't help either, though.